# Invalid reference in Terraform using Powershell

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Getting an error on my Terraform deployment for the following. I think it's because it's using a mixture of Terraform variables and Powershell I may have confused myself on the syntax.

Here is the Code:

```
    data "template_file" "ad-join-template" {
  template = <<EOF
  <powershell>
    # Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region eu-west-2
    # Set-Variable -name instance_id -value (Invoke-Restmethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
    # # New-SSMAssociation -target key=InstanceIds,Values=$instance_id -Name "${aws_ssm_document.ad-join-domain.name}"
    # New-SSMAssociation `
    #   -Name ad-join-domain `
    #   -Target @{
    #       "Key"="InstanceIds"
    #       "Values"="$($instance_id)"
    #     }

    $apiurl = "${var.API}"
    $tajdns = @("${taj_dns_server[0]}","[${taj_dns_server[1]}")

    $count = 0
    foreach ($dns in $tajdns){
        
        $returnedRecords = (Resolve-DnsName -Name $apiurl -Server $dns).IPAddress
        New-Variable -Name "dnsRecords$count" -Value $returnedRecords -Force
        $count++
        }

    $allDNSrecords += $dnsRecords0
    $allDNSrecords += $dnsRecords1

    $allDNSrecords = $allDNSrecords | Select-Object -Unique

    Add-Content C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts "`n***.**.*.* ssm.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com `
                                                      `n***.**.*.*  ssm.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com `
                                                      `n***.**.*.*  ssm.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com `
                                                      `n***.**.*.* ssmmessages.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com `
                                                      `n***.**.*.*  ssmmessages.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com `
                                                      `n***.**.*.*  ssmmessages.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com `
                                                      `n$allDNSrecords[0] ${var.API}`
                                                      `n$allDNSrecords[1] ${var.API}"

    $nicDetails = Get-NetAdapter
    Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $nicDetails.ifIndex -ServerAddresses (${local.concat_dns_servers_join})

    $domain = "${aws_directory_service_directory.ad.name}"
    $password = "${aws_directory_service_directory.ad.password}" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
    $username = "admin@$($domain)" 
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
    Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential
    Restart-Computer -Force
  </powershell>
  EOF
}
```

In the [${taj_dns_server[0]}]" this is pulling a Terraform variable out of list and populating it in to the script. Can you see if my syntax is correct?

Here is the Error:

```
│ Error: Invalid reference
136│ 
137│   on asg.tf line 19, in data "template_file" "ad-join-template":
138│   19:     $tajdns = @("[${taj_dns_server[0]}]","[${taj_dns_server[1]}]")
139│ 
140│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
141│ access, specifying the resource name.
142╵
143╷
144│ Error: Invalid reference
145│ 
146│   on asg.tf line 19, in data "template_file" "ad-join-template":
147│   19:     $tajdns = @("[${taj_dns_server[0]}]","[${taj_dns_server[1]}]")
148│ 
149│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
150│ access, specifying the resource name.
151╵
```

Comment: What is `taj_dns_server`? Perhaps you need `${var.taj_dns_server[0]}`?

Comment: Also, can you add that part of Terraform code, but the whole snippet, not just one line?

Comment: Updated the whole snippet

Comment: The square brackets in your terraform code and the error message don't match (e.g. ```"${taj_dns_server[0]}"``` vs ```"[${taj_dns_server[0]}]"```), and they don't balance in ```"[${taj_dns_server[1]}"```- could you confirm there's no typos in your terraform code?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest moving to `templatefile` function.

Comment: Got it to work. 

Needed to declare the variable correctly ..... `$tajdns = @(${var.taj_dns_server[0]},${var.taj_dns_server[1]})`

Can I ask why you recommend in moving into a `templatefile` function?

@MarkoE